# Method not running - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, uialertview

I have a very simply method. However in the method the UIAlertView will not run.... Here is my method:

```
-(void)post_result {
    NSLog(@"Post Result");

    post_now.enabled = YES;
    [active stopAnimating];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"You're post has been successfully uploaded." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    success_post_facebook = 0;
    success_post_youtube = 0;
    success_post_googleplus = 0;
    success_post_tumblr = 0;
    success_post_twitter = 0;

    NSLog(@"Post Result END");
}
```

The odd thing is that the code before and after the UIAlertView will run in this method.... So what an earth is wrong??

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Anything in the debugger? Are you calling this "post_result" in a separate thread? I would post more code if you expect to get a good answer.

Comment: What do you mean it won't run - does it not show?

Comment: Be sure you show the alert on the main thread.

Comment: How are you calling `post_result`?

Comment: Yes @rmaddy You are correct. I was calling the program from a Twitter API request via the built in Twitter API. This must have made the method running in a separate thread. Thanks.

Comment: On a side note, your message should read "Your post has been successfully uploaded." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are most likely calling that UIAlertView not on the main thread. To make it run on the main thread just use the main dispatch queue like so.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"You're post has been successfully uploaded." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `dispatch_sync()`?

Comment: Thanks and you could also do [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: I think. The issue was that I was calling the method from a Twitter API call via the built in Twitter framework. I think this was making it run on a separate thread.

Comment: @trojanfoe It only needs to be `dispatch_sync` is you want the background thread to block while the dispatched code runs on the main queue. No point to that in this case.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff you could use NSOperationQueue but it is really not needed in this case. Apple suggests you use GCD for this type of thing. NSOperations should mainly be used if you want to start/stop/resume things on separate threads which is not needed in your case.

Comment: @Pete42 Ah right ok. Thank you very much for the detailed information. Very helpful indeed.